# Getting the items of a ComboBox with its DataSource filled

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, controls, combobox

Consider that there is a ComboBox which is populated through its DataSource property. Each item in the ComboBox is a custom object and the ComboBox is set with a `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

```
IList<CustomItem> aItems = new List<CustomItem>();
//CustomItem has Id and Value and is filled through its constructor
aItems.Add(1, "foo"); 
aItems.Add(2, "bar");

myComboBox.DataSource = aItems;
```

Now the problem is that, I want to read the items as string that will be rendered in the UI. Consider that I don't know the type of each item in the ComboBox (`CustomItem` is unknown to me)

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Binding:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = aItems;
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
```

Getting the item:

```
CustomItem ci = ComboBox1.SelectedValue as CustomItem;
```

edit: If all that you want to get is a list of all of the display values of the combobox

```
List<String> displayedValues = new List<String>();
foreach (CustomItem ci in comboBox1.Items)
    displayedValues.Add(ci.Value);
```

Comment: Its about the items and not the selected one.

Answer (score 2):

Create an Interface, say `ICustomFormatter`, and have those custom objects implement it.

```
interface ICustomFormatter
{
   public string ToString();
}
```

Then call the `ToString()` method.

EDIT: link to [Decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) pattern.

Comment: Is this the only way ?? I cannot modify the CustomObject class. Is there any other way ???

Comment: Object defines a ToString() method. If you wanted to do this, you'd just override that instead of implementing a new interface.

Comment: Sounds like a better solution. I will try to modify the CustomItem, if I don't have permission, will go on with the 'decorator' stuff

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get at ValueMember and DisplayMember through reflection. But interrogating the combobox might be a little easier. The following will work, but maybe you want to surround it with SuspendUpdate or something.

```
string s = string.Empty;
int n = comboBox1.Items.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
    s = s + ';' + comboBox1.Text; // not SelectedText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although slightly more computationally expensive, Reflection could do what you want:

```
using System.Reflection;    
private string GetPropertyFromObject(string propertyName, object obj)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        if(pi != null)
        {
            object value = pi.GetValue(obj, null);
            if(value != null)
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
        }
        //return empty string, null, or throw error
        return string.Empty;
    }
```